# difference between 2 dates in days saved into new column as float

Tags: python, dataframe, time

I have a python dataframe with 2 columns that contain dates as strings e.g. start_date "2002-06-12" and end_date "2009-03-01". I would like to calculate the difference (days) between these 2 columns for each row and save the results into a new column called for example time_diff of type float.

I have tried:

```
df["time_diff"] = (pd.Timestamp(df.end_date) - pd.Timestamp(df.start_date )).astype("timedelta64[d]")
pd.to_numeric(df["time_diff"])
```

based on some tutorials but this gives `TypeError: Cannot convert input` for the first line. What do I need to change to get this running?

Comment: show few lines of you data frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
import numpy as np
enddates = np.asarray([pd.Timestamp(end) for end in df.end_date.values])
startdates = np.asarray([pd.Timestamp(start) for start in df.start_date.values])
df['time_diff'] = (enddates - startdates).astype("timedelta64")
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working example of converting a string column of a dataframe to datetime type and saving the time difference between the datetime columns in a new column as a float data type( number of seconds)

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta
tmp = [("2002-06-12","2009-03-01"),("2016-04-28","2022-03-14")]
df = pd.DataFrame(tmp,columns=["col1","col2"])

df["col1"]=pd.to_datetime(df["col1"])
df["col2"]=pd.to_datetime(df["col2"])

df["time_diff"]=df["col2"]-df["col1"]
df["time_diff"]=df["time_diff"].apply(timedelta.total_seconds)
```

Time difference in seconds can be converted to minutes or days by using simple math.

Comment: `df["time_diff"] = (df["col2"] - df["col1"]) / np.timedelta64(1, 's')`

Answer (score 2):

First convert strings to datetime, then calculate difference in days.

```
df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['time_diff'] = (df.end_date - df.start_date).dt.days
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it by converting your columns into date and then computing the difference :

```
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'Start Date' : ['2002-06-12', '2002-06-12' ], 'End date' : ['2009-03-01', '2009-03-06']})

df['Start Date'] = [  datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d").date() for x in df['Start Date'] ]
df['End date'] = [ datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d").date() for x in df['End date'] ]

df['Diff'] = df['End date'] - df['Start Date']
```

Out :

```
End date    Start Date  Diff
0   2009-03-01  2002-06-12  2454 days
1   2009-03-06  2002-06-12  2459 days
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just use `pd.to_datetime` to convert your string values:

```
df["time_diff"] = (pd.to_datetime(df.end_date) - pd.to_datetime(df.start_date))
```

The resul will automatically be a `timedelta64`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Arrived'] = [pd.Timestamp('01-04-2017')]
df['Left'] = [pd.Timestamp('01-06-2017')]
diff = df['Left'] - df['Arrived']
days = pd.Series(delta.days for delta in (diff)
result = days[0]
```